# Regression/compressive sensing with non-linear constrains where the coefficients are assumed to be integer or binary {0,1}

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

The following regression problem
$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}
$$
where $\mathbf{y}$ is a $N\times 1$ column real vector, $\mathbf{A}$ is a $N\times M$ real matrix where each column $\mathbf{a}_i$ can be called an atom, $N$ could be great than $M$, or $N=M$, or $N>M$. We want to solve $\mathbf{x}$ with minimal loss where

1. each entry of $\mathbf{x}$ is integers, i.e., $x_i=1,2,...,\infty$, or
2. each entry of $\mathbf{x}$ is either $0$ or $1$, $x_i=\{0,1\}$

How could I solve this problem ? any hint on existing implementation code or where could I find references on this field ?

Comment: Do you expect $x$ to be sparse?

Comment: Yes, surely. $\mathbf{x}$ need to be sparse for the constrains that $x_i$ is integer. However, I do not think the sparse constrains is needed for $x_i$ bing binary.

Comment: By sparse I meant that you expect most components of $x$ to be $0$.  Why is this expected in the first case and not the second?

Comment: I think binary itself is a form of sparsity and a strong constrain, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, if $50$ percent of the components of $x$ are $1$ and the rest are $0$, then it wouldn't be true that most entries of $x$ are $0$ and $x$ wouldn't be described as sparse.

Comment: Yes. However, sparse is needed for underdetermined problems where $\mathbf{A}$ is a fat matrix. This arise from the uncertainity in the space spanned by $\mathbf{x}$. With $\mathbf{x}$ being binary, the possible solutions of $\mathbf{x}$ lies on the cortex of axis with much reduced possible solutions, so the phase transition in this situation might be much better than $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbf{x}$ is integer. EDIT, we could surely assume $\mathbf{x}\in\{0,1\}$ is sparse in this situation.

Comment: Hmm.  For the second case, perhaps you could relax the constraint to $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$ and minimize $\|Ax - y \|^2$.  This would be a convex problem, so it could be solved easily (for example using CVX in Matlab) and we can hope the solution we get will have $x_i = 0$ or $x_i = 1$ for all $i$ or for most $i$.